# react-native is allowing me to directly manipulate props

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using react-native and react-redux to create a simple app.  Thus, all of my props are passed in from mapStateToProps, coming from redux.

I should have to use mapDispachToProps to manipulate the props but that is not what is happening.

I have an event handler that allows me to directly manipulate the props.  Why is this behavior occurring?

```
nameHandler(text) {
    console.log(this.props.group.name); //output: Billy
    this.props.group.name = 'illegal!';
    console.log(this.props.group.name); // output: illegal!
}
```

I am binding 'this' to 'nameHandler' within the constructor, but that doesn't seem relevant.

I've mostly gotten around this, but shouldn't this *not* be possible?

Comment: you are changing the prop of the group object and it does not affect the state in any way. You will lose this change once an action is dispatched to the store.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen that it goes away once I dispatch.  I am new to React, I just assumed it would complain if I tried to change props.  I appreciate the quick response!